# Attaching a file to an email and sending it using PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer, email-attachments

The file is not being sent, please help me identify what's wrong with my code.
The email is being sent and all the form data is being sent as well, except for the file.
I'm trying to send an attached file through email for the first time. I apologize if I don't understand obvious things. Is it possible that I need to upload the file to the server first?

```
<form class="uk-grid-small" name="contact-us" enctype="multipart/form-data" uk-grid>
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1">
                        <input class="uk-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contact name" aria-label="100">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-width-1-2@s">
                        <input class="uk-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-width-1-2@s">
                        <input class="uk-input" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" aria-label="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1">
                        <div style="background-color: #7185c1" class="uk-padding-small uk-border-rounded">
                            <div class="js-upload uk-placeholder uk-text-center uk-flex uk-flex-column uk-margin-remove-bottom  uk-border-rounded uk-flex-middle">
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-form-custom uk-border-rounded bg-color-white uk-width-1-4 uk-margin-bottom" uk-form-custom>
                                    <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
                                    <span class="uk-link choose-btn">CHOOSE FILE</span>
                                </button>
                                <span style="color: #fff" class="uk-text-middle">or drop file here</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <progress id="js-progressbar" class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100" hidden></progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin uk-width-1-1">
                        <textarea class="uk-textarea" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Notes of issue" aria-label="Notes of issue"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" uk-width-1-3@s">
                        <button class="uk-button uk-button-default submit-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**contact.js**

```
    $('[name="contact-us"]').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        let USER_DATA = new FormData(this);

        console.log(USER_DATA)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/contact-form.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: USER_DATA,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
           
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
              
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

**contact-form.php**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name = clean($_POST["name"]);
    $phone = clean($_POST["phone"]);
    $email = strtolower(clean($_POST["email"]));
    $textarea = clean($_POST["message"]);
    $file = $_FILES["file"];


    if(!empty($name) && !empty($phone) && !empty($email) && !empty($textarea)) {
        require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php');

        $mailBody = " test ";

                  

            $mail = new PHPMailer; // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->Host       = "mail.test.com.ua"; // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
            $mail->Host       = "mail.test.com.ua";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mail->Username   = "noreply@test.eu";  // GMAIL username
            $mail->Password   = "test";            // GMAIL password
            $mail->CharSet    = 'utf-8';


            $file = $_FILES['file'];  
        
            $mail->addAttachment($file['tmp_name'], $file['name']);  

            $mail->AddAddress('balshut@gmail.com');

            $mail->addReplyTo($email);
            $mail->AddBCC('noreply@test.eu');
            $mail->SetFrom('noreply@test.eu', 'test Contact');
            $mail->Subject = 'test Contact';
 
            $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
            $mail->MsgHTML($mailBody);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Is it possible that I need to upload the file to the server `...your AJAX code is already doing that. Are you really asking whether you need to move the uploaded file from its temporary location to a more permanent one (using `move_uploaded_file()`) before you try to attach it to the email?

Comment: PHPMailer 5.2.4 is over 10 years old and has several known vulnerabilities and many bugs, so I strongly suggest you [update immediately](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @ADyson Yes, do I need to use move_uploaded_file() ?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but I guess it's possible. Follow synchro's advice first though and upgrade PHPMailer to a recent version, in case that's the problem.

Comment: First things first - make sure you actually *have* an upload file. You may need to add `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` to your JS form, or it might omit file fields. After that, `var_dump($_FILES)` in your PHP to be sure you are receiving the file, and then definitely use `move_uploaded_file` on it. Only when those are all working as expected should you think about how to send it via email.

Comment: @Synchro I don't believe the AJAX code is the problem, what the OP has written correlates with other examples online of how to upload files using jQuery AJAX. jQuery will take care of the content type (and what's written on the HTML form isn't relevant when using AJAX). The OP should verify it of course, in the manner you suggest, but I'd be surprised if that's the root cause.

Comment: I suspect that too, but the key thing is verify each step - sending it via email is the last step; if that doesn't work, you don't know at what point it's breaking, so it's vital to start at the beginning of the chain. Take a look at the PHPMailer examples for [submitting via JS](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform-ajax.phps) and [sending attachments](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps), which will need to be combined for this question.

Comment: @AndriiBal One thing to definitely check as well is the content of `$_FILES["file"]["error"]`. Just because the file reached the server doesn't mean the server considered it to be valid. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php explains what the error codes mean.

Comment: Can you debug the SMTP connection and see what you are sending? you can use https://mailsnag.com as SMTP server and it has SMTP log and RAW files for the emails you sent.